# Gem for database auto backup in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Which gem is used in ruby on rails for creating a automatically generate a backup of database ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [backup gem](https://github.com/backup/backup) to backup your database and [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to schedule the backup so that you can run backup periodically. For more info: [Backup a Rails Database With the Backup and Whenever Gems](http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/06/30/backup-a-rails-database-with-the-backup-and-whenever-gems/)

Comment: I am trying to install backup gem but it is giving an error [2017/03/20 05:05:50][error] Notifier::Error: Notifier::Mail Failed!
[2017/03/20 05:05:50][error] --- Wrapped Exception ---
[2017/03/20 05:05:50][error] OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "xyz" does not match the server certificate how can I fix this ?

Comment: how did you install the gem

Comment: http://www.agiratech.com/auto-backup-of-database-in-rails-application/ from this site . when I am executing this command backup perform --trigger your_backup , that time error is coming .

Comment: have you given some invalid hostname xyz anywhere?

Comment: No, I have given the valid hostname than also it is throughing an error .